# Pattern Matching Terms with Plus or Minus

Tags: pattern-matching

I was playing with pattern matching and I ran into something I didn't expect. I imagine the following line would return `True`, but it returns `False`:

```
MatchQ[x, (+1 | -1) a_]
```

This will return `True`:

```
MatchQ[-x, (+1 | -1) a_]
```

Digging slightly deeper with `FullForm` I find the reason for this; `FullForm[-a]` returns `Times[-1, a]` whereas `FullForm[a]`, of course, returns `a`. What's the best way to return `True` for both cases? Does *Mathematica* have an equivalent to the `?` symbol in regular expressions which matches a group zero or one times?

I've also tried

```
MatchQ[x, (Nothing | -1) a_]
```

which again returns `False`.

Comment: This would work: `MatchQ[x, fact_. a_Symbol /; Abs[fact] == 1]`  It matches only if the factor in front of a symbol is +1 or -1.  `Nothing` is not meant to be used in pattern matching.

Comment: What would be an example of a match failure you would hope to see with the pattern you are searching for?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you, `_.` was just what I needed to know about. @Alan `2x` would fail to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FullForm` (and `Head`) is useful in seeing what lies under the hood.

```
FullForm@x
```

> x

```
Head@x
```

> Symbol

and

```
FullForm@-x
```

> Times[-1,x]

```
Head@-x
```

> Times

Now

```
(+1 | -1) a_ // FullForm
```

> Times[Alternatives[1,-1],Pattern[a,Blank[]]]

That's why `-x` matches the pattern and `x` does not. For a fix:

```
MatchQ[x, -1 a_ | _Symbol]
```

> True

```
MatchQ[-x, -1 a_ | _Symbol]
```

> True

```
MatchQ[2 x, -1 a_ | _Symbol]
```

> False

```
MatchQ[-2 x, -1 a_ | _Symbol]
```

> False